# on last page next link vanishes and previous link never showed up start to end

Tags: php, sql, pagination

I can not understand what i am not doing.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from customers";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $rows = $row[0];
    $page_rows = 3;
    $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 
    if($last<1) {
        $last = 1;
    }
    $pagenum = 1;
    if(isset($_GET['pn'])) {        
        $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#','',$_GET['pn']);
    } 
    if($pagenum<1) {
        $pagenum=1;
    } else 
        if($pagenum>$last) {
            $pagenum = $last;
        }

    $start = ($pagenum-1)*$page_rows;
    $end = $page_rows;  
    $textline ="page<b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>" ;
    $paginationCtrl='';
    if($last!=1) {
        if($pagenum>1) {
            // here i am giving the previous link to variable pagination.
            $previous = $pagenum-1;
            $paginationCtrl .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?     pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';

            //If i print this this variable then it shows it value.

            for($i=$pagenum-4; $i<$pagenum; $i++) {
                if($i>0) {
                    $paginationCtrl .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                }
            }
        }
        $paginationCtrl=''.$pagenum.'&nbsp;';
        for($i=$pagenum+1; $i<=$last; $i++) {                   
            $paginationCtrl .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            if($i>=$pagenum+4) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if($pagenum!=$last) {
            // Here i am defiinig next link which appeared untill the last page is clicked. if user is on last page it also disappeared.

            $next = $pagenum+1;
            $paginationCtrl .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a>';
        }
    }
?>
<div class="box-body">
    <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>                    
            <tr>
                <th>Customer Name</th>                               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
<?php               
        $sql2 = "SELECT * from customers order by customer_id DESC LIMIT $start,$end";   
        $query2 = mysql_query($sql2);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) { ?>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </tbody>                                
    </table>
```

Here it shows like 1 2 3 next and if i am on page 2. it shows like 3 next.

```
<div><?php echo $paginationCtrl; ?>  </div>
```

if i have 3 pages total. and i am on page 2 the previous link is not appearing. and if i am on last page the next link also disappeared. and paginationctrl variable only showing page 3. no previous pages or links shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> on last page next link vanishes

Yes, but it is good. On last page, there is not a next page.

If you want show a not active “next” link you can change your code in something like this:

```
if( $pagenum!=$last )
{
    $next = $pagenum+1;
    $paginationCtrl .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a>';
}
else
{
    $paginationCtrl .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="inactive">Next</div>';
}
```

> previous link never showed up start to end

You have a typo. Replace this line:

```
$paginationCtrl=''.$pagenum.'&nbsp;';
```

with:

```
$paginationCtrl .= '' . $pagenum . '&nbsp;';
```